# Get all modified files with pipeline and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, git, groovy, bash, pipeline

I'm trying to get all changed files in repository, by running bash script inside Jenkins pipeline

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
files=($(git whatchanged --name-only --pretty="" origin..HEAD))
'''
```

But getting error

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

It's works on my local machine but does not works in pipeline.